# signedness vs bit size

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Given example below, with the simulators I've tried, the value of `d2` is created by sign extending `4'sd2 - i1`.  From, my reading of the standard (1800-2012) I expect `4'sd2 - i1` to be treated as unsigned and zero extended in the same way as for `d1`.

What am I missing?  Does the unsignedness of `i1` somehow change as it is being widened from 2 to 4 bits?  Thanks.

```
module sign_test(input clk, input /*unsigned*/ [1:0] i1,
                 output reg [7:0] d1, output reg [7:0] d2);
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    d1 = $unsigned(4'sd2 - i1); // this gets zero extended; the only possible values for 'd1' are 0, 1, 2 and 0x0f
    d2 = 4'sd2 - i1; // this gets sign extended; the only possible values for 'd2' are 0, 1, 2 and 0xff
    // but 11.8.1 says "4'sd2 - i1" should be unsigned:
    //  "-- For non-self-determined operands, the following rules apply:
    //       [...]
    //       -- If any operand is unsigned, the result is unsigned,
    //          regardless of the operator."
    // and 'i1' is unsigned by default (adding "unsigned"
    // explicitly doesn't change the behaviour).
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for the difference is not to do with whether each expression is signed or unsigned, but instead to do with the number of bits Verilog uses to do the calculation.

This is a *context-determined expression*:

```
d2 = 4'sd2 - i1;
```

That means Verilog uses the maximum of all the widths involved (the widths of `d2`, `4'sd2` and `i1`, which is 8 (the width of `d2`). As you say unsigned arithmetic is done. With a value of `2'b11` for `i1`:

```
d2 = 00000010 - 00000011
```

which is

```
11111111
```

With

```
  d1 = $unsigned(4'sd2 - i1);
```

however, the width of `d1` is not taken into account, because of the call to the `$unsigned` system function. This makes the expression `4'sd2 - i1` a *self-determined expression* and so the bit width used for the calculation is 4 - the maximum of the widths of `4'sd2` and `i1`. So

```
0010 - 0011
```

is

```
1111
```

This is then zero-padded to

```
00001111
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/duY